# How to format time-series data with multiple categories and numerical data related to each category for input into a Tensorflow model?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to format data for a regression problem in Tensorflow using an LSTM model. The data is a time series where the data for each timestamp has categorical data with numerical data related to those categories and numerical data unrelated to those categories.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
  font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Time</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Person</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Height</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Weight</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Location of Sun</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Location of Moon</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">00:00</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">A</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">B</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">7</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">C</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">00:05</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">D</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">A</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">00:10</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">B</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">C</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There are a fixed number of categories that can appear in the time series but the number of categories that appear at a particular time stamp is variable. I was thinking of using `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer` to tokenize the categorical data but I'm unsure how to format the data to use as an input to the neural network while the structure of the data.

I feel like my question may not be 100% clear so if you would like me to clarify something please comment below